# Cloud Explorer errors when trying to view IoT Hub - Newtonsoft dependency error

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, visual-studio-2019, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Repro steps:

1. Install Azure IoT Edge Tools for VS 2019
2. Install Cloud Explorere for VS Preview
3. Open Cloud Explorer and navigate to my IoT hub
   4 .Try to view devices

I expected to see my hub devices, instead I get the error:

> Cloud Explorer
>
> Unable to retrieve child resources.
>
> Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version 10.0.0.0, Culture…

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same steps as you but could not reproduce the error. It did work for me. I was able to browse through the available devices as shown below:

[image: Cloud Explorer VS 2019]

I'm on version `16.3.6` of VS 2019. Please ensure you too have the latest version of VS 2019 and also the mentioned extensions and give it another try. Remember to restart VS after the installation/updates. If the issue still persists, please open an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Hope this helps!